# How to get value of async storage in node js

Tags: node.js, react-native

I saved token using async storage in react-native. Is there any way I can get this token value in the Node.js backend?

Comment: this [link] help you to get you solution (https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/api) _italic_ **bold**

Answer (score 0):

According to https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage you can get the item from the storage. You will have to POST it to the backend may be using `fetch`

```js
fetch('https://example.com/uploadtoken', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(TOKEN),
}).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
  console.log('Success:', data);
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});
```